# Confused Using scikits.cuda.cula

Tags: python, cuda, scikits

I want to use some of cula functionality like LU factorization or Matrix inverse but I have some problem regarding the pointer inputs. for example for doing LU factorization with scikits.cuda.cula.culaDeviceSgetrf(m, n, a, lda, ipiv) , one need to use pointer f "a" argument but there is no pointer in python explicitly(I know all variables in python are by ref) . So what should I do in this case? should I use ctype library to create python?

this is what I am trying to do:

```
   import numpy as np

   import scikits.cuda.cula as cula
   import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

   cula.culaInitialize()

   //I create a square matrix for simplicity 
   a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9],[7,2,3,5],[2,4,5,6]])

   n=b.shape[0]
   ida=ipv=m

   scikits.cuda.cula.culaDeviceSgetrf(m,n,a,n,n)
```

> status = _libcula.culaDeviceSgetrf(m, n, int(a), lda, int(ipiv))
>   TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

and when I try

```
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
scikits.cuda.cula.culaDeviceSgetrf(m,n,a_gpu,n,n) :
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikits.cuda-0.042-py2.7.egg/scikits/cuda/cula.py",
>   line 329, in culaDeviceSgetrf status = _libcula.culaDeviceSgetrf(m, n,
>   int(a), lda, int(ipiv)) TypeError: int() argument must be a string or
>   a number, not 'GPUArray'

any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. You cannot pass a `gpuarray` directly to these routines, the array argument is expected to be a device pointer which is internally cast to a Python `ctypes.c_void_p` for passing to the CULA library. PyCUDA's `gpuarray` includes a member `ptr` which will return the underlying pointer to the GPU memory.

If you do something like:

```
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
scikits.cuda.cula.culaDeviceSgetrf(m,n,a_gpu.ptr,n,n)
```

it should work correctly [disclaimer: never compiled, or tested, use at own risk].

Comment: thanks for your reply I fixed this issue by using a_gpu.gpudata. this is the link related to this issuehttps://github.com/lebedov/scikits.cuda/issues/20#issuecomment-8202795